# how to solve following issue with apache spark with optimal solution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

i need to solve the following problem without graphframe please help.
Input Dataframe

```
|-----------+-----------+--------------|
| ID        | prev      | next         |
|-----------+-----------+--------------|
| 1         | 1         | 2            |
| 2         | 1         | 3            |
| 3         | 2         |  null        |
| 9         | 9         | null         |
|-----------+-----------+--------------|
```

output dataframe

```
|-----------+------------|
| bill_id   | item_id    |
|-----------+------------|
| 1         | [1, 2, 3]  |
| 9         | [9]        |
|-----------+------------|
```

Comment: what rules should be applied to the input to get the output? Here are somethings to help you ask on SO -- [ask], [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably quite inefficient, but it works.  It is inspired by how graphframes does connected components.  Basically join with itself on the `prev` column until it doesn't get any lower, then group.

```
df = sc.parallelize([(1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (3, 2, None), (9, 9, None)]).toDF(['ID', 'prev', 'next'])
df.show()

+---+----+----+
| ID|prev|next|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   1|   2|
|  2|   1|   3|
|  3|   2|null|
|  9|   9|null|
+---+----+----+

converged = False
count = 0
while not converged:
    step = df.join(df.selectExpr('ID as prev', 'prev as lower_prev'), 'prev', 'left').cache()
    print('step', count)
    step.show()
    converged = step.where('prev != lower_prev').count() == 0
    df = step.selectExpr('ID', 'lower_prev as prev')
    print('df', count)
    df.show()
    count += 1

step 0
+----+---+----+----------+
|prev| ID|next|lower_prev|
+----+---+----+----------+
|   2|  3|null|         1|
|   1|  2|   3|         1|
|   1|  1|   2|         1|
|   9|  9|null|         9|
+----+---+----+----------+

df 0
+---+----+
| ID|prev|
+---+----+
|  3|   1|
|  1|   1|
|  2|   1|
|  9|   9|
+---+----+

step 1
+----+---+----------+
|prev| ID|lower_prev|
+----+---+----------+
|   1|  3|         1|
|   1|  1|         1|
|   1|  2|         1|
|   9|  9|         9|
+----+---+----------+

df 1
+---+----+
| ID|prev|
+---+----+
|  3|   1|
|  1|   1|
|  2|   1|
|  9|   9|
+---+----+

df.groupBy('prev').agg(F.collect_set('ID').alias('item_id')).withColumnRenamed('prev', 'bill_id').show()

+-------+---------+
|bill_id|  item_id|
+-------+---------+
|      1|[1, 2, 3]|
|      9|      [9]|
+-------+---------+
```